# A program that asks the network address, number of host bits, and the number of subnetworks, and then shows the correct subnetwork address

Tags: python, networking

Now, i fix it. it shows the correct output. Only, problem is it's output have braces and quotation's every string indexes because it is still a string. How can I remove the braces from the output? Is there a command in python for that?

```
networkAddress = raw_input('Enter network address: ')
n = input('Enter number of network bits: ')
h = 32-n
hostAddressOut = 2**h
hostAddress = 0
x = input('Enter number of subnets: ')
octet = networkAddress.split('.')

for i in range(x):

    if hostAddress > 255:
        hostAddress = 0
        thirdOctet = int(octet[2])+1
        octet[2] = str(thirdOctet)
        octet[3] = str(hostAddress)
        print 'subnet', i, ' = ', octet
        hostAddress = hostAddressOut
    else:
        octet[3] = str(hostAddress)
        print 'subnet', i, ' = ', octet
        hostAddress = hostAddress + hostAddressOut
```

Here is the sample output.
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ULaKP.png)

Comment: FYI: https://ericlippert.com/2014/03/05/how-to-debug-small-

Answer (score 2):

It is not showing any output because your final `if` is:

```
if '.' == 2:
```

This condition always returns `false`, hence nothing is printed.

Also, here:

```
if i == '.':
    if '.' == 2:  # As mentioned this is incorrect
        start = int(i)
        # .....something
```

You are checking for `i == '.'` and then doing `int(i)`. This will always raise error because you can't convert "." to `int`.

Comment: I fix it now, using octet.split('.'), a for loop and if, else condition. The output will iterate its hostAddress, and when the hostAddress > 255, it goes back to 0, and the third octet is +1.

Comment: Another problem is that, the output has braces.(the entire octet is still a string). How can I remove the braces? Is there a command for that?

Comment: Can you please share what value you have and what you desire? I am not clear about your issue right now

Comment: look at the edited question